# "Ambiguous use of 'children'" when trying to use NSTreeController.arrangedObjects in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, nstreecontroller

I get an `Ambiguous use of 'children'` error in **XCode 8.0/Swift 3.0** when trying to send a message to the opaque `NSTreeController.arrangedObjects` object.

Here is a bare playground showing the use case :

```
import AppKit

extension NSTreeController {

    func whatever () {
        let k = (self.arrangedObjects as AnyObject).children // error here
    }
}
```

I try to use `AnyObject` as a bridge to the underlying ObjC object, which is supposed to be able to get through any method call, I guess.

Xcode signals that it found two candidates that could respond to a "children" message: `Foundation.XMLNode` and `AppKit.NSTreeNode`.

Of course the obvious solution (casting to `NSTreeNode`) is not working because `arrangedObjects` returns an opaque, proxy object not a real `NSTreeNode`

Any suggestion on how we're supposed to use `NSTreeController.arrangedObjects.children` in Swift 3 ?

Comment: Cast `arrangedObjects` to the actual type rather than `AnyObject` (`arrangedObjects as! NSTreeNode`)

Comment: @vadian : As I said in the question, `arrangedObjects` doesn't return a `NSTreeNode` so the cast is failing at runtime.

Comment: Then cast it to what it actually returns.

Comment: Not so simple, unfortunately. Actually `arrangedObjects` returns a `_NSControllerTreeProxy`, which is a non-public class. If I try to cast to it then it doesn't even compile (`Use of undeclared type '_NSControllerTreeProxy'`). The proxy object is guaranteed to respond to a couple of messages only, one of them being `children`, and it's not supposed to be used otherwise.

Comment: I have no experience with NSTreeController and cannot test if it works correctly, but `let k = (self.arrangedObjects as AnyObject).children as [NSTreeNode]?` at least compiles.

Comment: @MartinR : worked perfectly !! Please make it an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two candidates for the `children` property differ by their type:

```
Foundation.XMLNode:137:14: note: found this candidate
    open var children: [XMLNode]? { get }
             ^
AppKit.NSTreeNode:12:14: note: found this candidate
    open var children: [NSTreeNode]? { get }
             ^
```

You can resolve the ambiguity by casting the value of the property
to the expected type. In your case:

```
let k = (self.arrangedObjects as AnyObject).children as [NSTreeNode]?
```

Comment: That's the only valid solution to my knowledge. I've played a lot with `#selector(children())` and similar, but to no avail.

Comment: It seems that, as in Xcode 8.2.1, this doesn't work with the "whole module optimization" compiler option.

Comment: @LShi I'll double-check it later.

Comment: I tried to move the code to an Swift extension of `NSTreeController`, a method called `rootNodes`, still had no luck with the whole module optimization.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. Could you tell me how you discovered the two candidates containing `children`?

Comment: @jeff-h: By looking at the full compiler messages in the "Report navigator" in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

## Another solution: Adding an Obj-C category to NSTreeController

### .h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSTreeController (RootNodes_m)

- (NSArray *) rootNodes;

@end
```

### .m

```
#import "NSTreeController+RootNodes_m.h"

@implementation NSTreeController (RootNodes_m)

- (NSArray *) rootNodes {
    NSObject *  arranged = self.arrangedObjects;

    if ([arranged respondsToSelector: @selector(childNodes)]) {
        return [arranged performSelector:@selector(childNodes)];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Now in your code you can use it like this:

```
return treeController.rootNodes() as? [NSTreeNode]
```

I had problem with the above answer: The compiler refused to compile when "whole module optimization" was turned on. A swift extension didn't help. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1.