# `NSTreeController`'s `arrangedObjects` doesn't respond to `children`

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nstreecontroller

In the `NSTreeController`'s `arrangedObjects` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstreecontroller/1527465-arrangedobjects) it says:

> The value of this property represents a proxy root tree node
>   containing the tree controller’s sorted content objects. The proxy
>   object responds to children and descendant(at:) messages. This
>   property is observable using key-value observing.

But in the following code the `if` never hits its body.

```
#import "NSTreeController+RootNodes_m.h"

@implementation NSTreeController (RootNodes_m)

- (NSArray *) rootNodes {
    NSObject *  arranged = self.arrangedObjects;

    if ([arranged respondsToSelector: @selector(children)]) {
        return [arranged performSelector:@selector(children)];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

I wrote this Obj-C category because in my Swift project I can't turn on "whole module optimization" when I archive the product for release when using a "hack" from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660939/ambiguous-use-of-children-when-trying-to-use-nstreecontroller-arrangedobject/39661700?noredirect=1#comment71140148_39661700). So I tried adding this category, which got me even "worse" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using Objective-C, you should look at the [Objective-C version of the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstreecontroller/1527465-arrangedobjects?language=objc). The page you linked to has a Language selector toward the top-right.

In the Objective-C docs, you'll find that the proxy responds to `-childNodes`, not `-children`.

Comment: Thanks! Now with this Obj-C category, the whole module optimization also works. I tried adding a Swift extension but to no vail.