# How do I save the order of sourcelist items?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstreecontroller

I have an NSOutlineView as a sourcelist, like Mail.app. Its content is bound to an NSTreeController, which manages an array of my model objects. I've implemented drag-and-drop on the sourcelist and this is working perfectly.

Now I'd like to *save* the new ordering when the user finishes a drag-and-drop action in the sidebar. However, I can't find anything describing how this would usually be done.

The best I can come up with is:

- add a `treeIndex` property to my model class, to store the model's position in the sourcelist
- after a drop action, go through each node in the NSTreeController, and store each node's index in the model's `treeIndex` property

The problem is, I can't find how to retrieve the arranged objects from the NSTreeController. I can't get `treeController.arrangedObjects` to give me anything useful!

Searching through Github repos I've seen numerous uses of `treeController.arrangedObjects.childNodes!!` but that just throws a `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'children'` syntax error for me.

The following pseudo-code might help describe what I am trying to do after each drop action:

```
let parentNode = treeController.nodeAtIndex([0, 0])
for childNode in parentNode.children {
   (childNode.representedObject as SidebarItem).indexPosition = childNode.index
}
```

Comment: Which line of the pseudo-code is the problem?

Comment: The first line really... although I finally discovered http://stackoverflow.com/a/39661700/2778502 which showed me this: `let treeNodes = (treeController.arrangedObjects as AnyObject).children as [NSTreeNode]?` and that got me going. Therefore for me the focus of the question is now more philosophical (is this the best approach) and less about implementation (what syntax do I need to pull this off).